# Simulating circuits online, oscilloscope?

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, oscilloscope

I'm playing around with some op-amp tutorials, trying to get a grip on how they work. I'd like to build some of them to get a better grip on how they work. I'm on CircuitLab right now since I've got a student license, but I can't seem to find anything resembling an oscilloscope.

For example, I wanted to build a op-amp square wave converter circuit and play around with the resistances and other components right now and watch the response in a scope. What's the best way?

Comment: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Comment: http://www.ti.com/tool/tina-ti

Comment: You don't add the 'scope as an element in the circuit. You just push the "simulate" button, then tell it what node voltages you want to graph after the simulation completes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend NI Multisim, its not an online software but it has [student version](http://www.ni.com/academic/multisimse.htm) that its very easy to use and you can download for free.

The best thing that I recommend for you its the simulate mode of the program that has a real Tektronix oscilloscope to use. So you can practice the osciloscope handling too.

[image]

Comment: The Tek simulator looks pretty sweet.

Comment: It's actually pretty clumsy if you've used a real Tek scope. The generic one is better for simulation.

Comment: I wonder how much money Tek paid them to have them use their scope as the image.